# Relation between three normally distributed random variables

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes

We have $N_1, N_2, N_3$ normally distributed random variables with $µ_i  =E[N_i]$, $ σ_{ij}=Cov(N_i,N_j)$.
 How can I write a relation between these three random variables to prove that:
 $E[N_i|N_2 = x] = µ_i + (x - µ_2)σ_{i2}/σ_{22}$,
 $Cov(N_i,N_j|N_2 = x] = σ_{ij} - σ_{i2}σ_{j2}/σ_{22}$ and
 $Var(N_1 - N_3|N_2 = x) = σ ̃_{11} - 2σ ̃_{13} + σ ̃_{33}$,
 where the tilde refers to the conditional distribution with respect to $N_2 = x$.
 Even a partial answer would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you want $N_1, N_2, N_3$ to have a _jointly_ normal distribution? or just be individually normal random variables that need not be jointly normal?

Comment: They need not be jointly normal.

Comment: I also verified the first condition on paper. And I found a similar answer involving matrix here http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/30588/deriving-the-conditional-distributions-of-a-multivariate-normal-distribution. But I'm wondering if there is a way to prove the last two conditions without using matrix.

Comment: Matrices simply provide a convenient short-hand for writing umpteen equations. The proof you need can be written out without mentioning matrices at all but I don't know what additional insight that will gain you.

Comment: It checks out, but the second equation needs quite of bit of work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Partial answer:

If $N_1, N_2, N_3$ are *jointly* normal random variables, then the *conditional* distribution of $N_i, i \in \{1, 3\}$ *given* that $N_2 = x$ is a 
normal distribution with mean $\mu_i + \frac{\sigma_{i2}}{\sigma_{22}}(x-\mu_2)$.
Thus, joint normality *suffices* to have the first of your conditions hold. 
Joint normality might be necessary too, but I need to think about that a bit more.